# Magento: collection on products in more than one category

Tags: magento

I'm having a strange problem where the product collection doesn't return any products when filtering by category IDs and when a product that should be included in the result is assigned to more than one category. Here it goes.

Product `ABC` is assigned to categories `91` and `558`.

Here's the Magento code (actual code):

```
$categoryIds = array(91,369);
$collection = mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','price','special_price','sku','small_image'))
    ->joinField('category_id',  // add category ID field to collection
        'catalog_category_product',
        'category_id',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        null,
        'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds));
```

Corresponding query

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_category_id`.`category_id` 
    FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
        LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `at_category_id`
            ON (at_category_id.`product_id`=e.entity_id) 
WHERE (at_category_id.category_id IN(91, 369));
```

This returns product `ABC`.

Now, `ABC` is in two categories as mentioned at the beginning. So, if I set `$categoryIds = array(91,558)`, it should do `...WHERE (at_category_id.category_id IN(91, 558))` and return `ABC` twice. However.. some kind of error (not logged) occurs and nothing is returned. Since there is no trace of logging for some reason, I didn't know what the problem was. Then, I added `->group(array('sku'))` and it works and returns `ABC` once.. (won't work if grouped by other columns). Why is this so?

I think I read somewhere that the product collection won't let you have duplicate entity IDs.. in which case it would make sense. But why no errors?

Comment: That's how collections works in Magento, ID key need to be unique int.
After SQL is run, magento fetches results, and adds it to collection, but if there records with same ID, it will overwrite existing one. So maybe try to add `CONCAT(product_id, categoryID)` to have it as an ID field (it will be some kind unique now), and it should return two values.